# A question about simple and finitely-generated objects in Grothendieck categories

Tags: abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a Grothendieck category and consider the following conditions:

(LFG) $\mathcal{E}$ is locally finitely generated (that is, the finitely generated objects of $\mathcal{E}$ generate this category);

(S) each non-zero object of $\mathcal{E}$ has a simple subquotient;

(S') the injective hulls of simple objects of $\mathcal{E}$ cogenerate it.

It is easy to see that (LFG)$\Rightarrow$(S)$\Leftrightarrow$(S'). It is also classical that (LFG) implies Grothendieck's condition (AB6). It is moreover known that the converse implication fails: Jan-Erik Roos gave a simple and beautiful example of a Grothendieck category satisfying (AB6) – and also (AB4*) – but not (LFG), and even not (S), at the end of his article [*Derived functors of inverse limits revisited.* J. London Math. Soc. (2) 73 (2006), no. 1, 65–83](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024610705022416).

My questions are:

- can one exhibit a Grothendieck category satisfying (S) but not (AB6)?
- can one exhibit a Grothendieck category satisfying (S) and (AB6) but not (LFG)?

(Of course, inspired by Roos example, it would be nice to have also (AB4*).)